# How to convert a string to formatted text C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to convert a string to formatted text in C# in WPF application, how to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: A string already contains formatted text. Why don't you be more specific?

Comment: Please read the `do your homework` section in [ask]

Comment: I have taken away the [tag:KINECT] tag since this has nothing to do with Kinect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the normal C# tools to do this.

However, if the entire purpose is to make a nice string for binding, you may be able to use the binding's [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) directly.

For example, you can have a TextBlock like so:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} at distance of {1}m.">
        <Binding Path="User"/>
        <Binding Path="Distance"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

This will format the text based off the "User" and "Distance" bound values.